# Keras: val_loss is increasing and evaluate loss is too high

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I'm new to Keras and I'm using it to build a normal Neural Network to classify number MNIST dataset. 
Beforehand I have already split the data into 3 parts: 55000 to train, 5000 to evaluate and 10000 to test, and I have scaled the pixel density down (by dividing it by 255.0) 
My model looks like this:

```
model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=[28,28]))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
```

And here is the compile:

```
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer = 'Adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I train the model:

```
his = model.fit(xTrain, yTrain, epochs = 20, validation_data=(xValid, yValid))
```

At first the val_loss decreases, then it increases although the accuracy is increasing.

```
Train on 55000 samples, validate on 5000 samples
Epoch 1/20
55000/55000 [==============================] - 5s 91us/sample - loss: 0.2822 - accuracy: 0.9199 - val_loss: 0.1471 - val_accuracy: 0.9588
Epoch 2/20
55000/55000 [==============================] - 5s 82us/sample - loss: 0.1274 - accuracy: 0.9626 - val_loss: 0.1011 - val_accuracy: 0.9710
Epoch 3/20
55000/55000 [==============================] - 5s 83us/sample - loss: 0.0899 - accuracy: 0.9734 - val_loss: 0.0939 - val_accuracy: 0.9742
Epoch 4/20
55000/55000 [==============================] - 5s 84us/sample - loss: 0.0674 - accuracy: 0.9796 - val_loss: 0.0760 - val_accuracy: 0.9770
Epoch 5/20
55000/55000 [==============================] - 5s 94us/sample - loss: 0.0541 - accuracy: 0.9836 - val_loss: 0.0842 - val_accuracy: 0.9742

Epoch 15/20
55000/55000 [==============================] - 4s 82us/sample - loss: 0.0103 - accuracy: 0.9967 - val_loss: 0.0963 - val_accuracy: 0.9788
Epoch 16/20
55000/55000 [==============================] - 5s 84us/sample - loss: 0.0092 - accuracy: 0.9973 - val_loss: 0.0956 - val_accuracy: 0.9774
Epoch 17/20
55000/55000 [==============================] - 5s 82us/sample - loss: 0.0081 - accuracy: 0.9977 - val_loss: 0.0977 - val_accuracy: 0.9770
Epoch 18/20
55000/55000 [==============================] - 5s 85us/sample - loss: 0.0076 - accuracy: 0.9977 - val_loss: 0.1057 - val_accuracy: 0.9760
Epoch 19/20
55000/55000 [==============================] - 5s 83us/sample - loss: 0.0063 - accuracy: 0.9980 - val_loss: 0.1108 - val_accuracy: 0.9774
Epoch 20/20
55000/55000 [==============================] - 5s 85us/sample - loss: 0.0066 - accuracy: 0.9980 - val_loss: 0.1056 - val_accuracy: 0.9768
```

And when I evaluate the loss is too high:

```
model.evaluate(xTest, yTest)
```

Result:

```
10000/10000 [==============================] - 0s 41us/sample - loss: 25.7150 - accuracy: 0.9740
[25.714989705941953, 0.974]
```

Is this ok, or is it a sign of overfitting? Should I do something to improve it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, it is not Ok. You want the loss rate to be as small as possible. Your result is typical for overfitting. Your Network 'knows' its training data, but isn't capable of analysing new Images. You may want to add some layers. Maybe Convolutional Layers, Dropout Layer... another idea would be to augment your training images. The `ImageDataGenerator`-Class provided by Keras might help you out here

Another thing to look at could be your hyperparameters. Why do you use 100 nodes in the first `dense` layer? maybe something like 784 (28*28) seems more interesting if you want to start with a `dense` layer. I would suggest some combination of `Convolutional`-`Dropout`-`Dense`. Then your `dense` -layer maybe doesn't need that many nodes...

Comment: This answer is unclear. If overfitting is the problem, adding layers at random will only result in _more_ overfitting. Dropout layers on the other hand could help. What do you mean by "loss rate" and by "usually, this is not ok"? And why does a size of 784 "seem more interesting"?

Comment: @ Mathias Müller  I never said something about adding layers 'at random' i was just mentioning that 2 dense layers maybe will not be enough, that's why I suggested using Convolutional Layers since they are highly used for Image-Data interpretation... But of course, the author of the question can't just add some layers randomly... he may need a better and larger structure of layers. With 'loss rate' i refer to his Loss of 25,7150 in his 'Result', and he asked if it is 'ok' if it is that high(very end of his question) so answered it is not.

Comment: @Mathias Müller it seems 'more interesting' because of 100 nodes sound a bit random and using a number of nodes like 784 MIGHT bring better results. But there is no such thing like a 'Right' Amount of nodes...it always takes adjustments and fine-tuning, so I suggested using values that in some way relate to his dataset, not just a random value of 100

Comment: It is contradictory to - at the same time - 1) state that the problem is overfitting and 2) recommend adding capacity to the model. Adding more layers will lead to _more_ overfitting. This is bad advice. It would be more helpful to recommend a high-capacity model, combined with early stopping on validation data.

Comment: @Mathias Müller Sorry if I wasn't clear. I am addressing 2 problems. First one is overfitting, which can be solved with dropout and data augmentation. the second one is the Model-Structure itself, my point was, that when his network stops overfitting he still might want to think about using a CNN which may produce better results.

And as far as I experienced does adding more layers not always lead to more overfitting, that might be the case, but in some project I had, it didn't seem to happen.